# UITableView default row height Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I want to program a table view, but there's a problem.
If I set one or more Cells the height of the rows is correct, but when the table view contains no cells, the height of the rows is too low. How can I change the default row height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0;
```

you should be able to set the row height, even when the table is empty.

Using

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

would not work in this case as it is only called when there is content to put into the Row.